# MS ACCESS: Code to validate data in table

Tags: ms-access

Below I have some code I've written to validate whether the user entered data on a form, which populates a table.  I am trying to confirm whether they have left field (MinAge) null.  I am getting a data mismatch when I run the code.  Is this the best way to do this?  Help!

```
 Dim MinAgeVal As Integer
 MinAgeVal = DLookup("[MinAge]", "User_ProductDefaultsAge")


 If MinAgeVal Is Null Then


    x = MsgBox("Missing Minimum Age Value", vbCritical)

Else

    x = MsgBox("clear", vbCritical)

End If
```

Also, the may be multiple rows within the table.

(UPDATED):

Ok... I have a table, which is populated by a user from a form. The user will enter a series of age ranges (min and max)... 0 - 5, 6 - 10, etc... each min / max range will be on its own row... I need to write code that will check each row for three things... 1) that there aren't any fields (min or max) that are null... 2) that the min range is not greater or equal to the max range... the the next row of data is in sequential order (max year of record 1 is less than the min year of record 2)

Min Year   Max Year
0             1
2             10
              15

Below, some code was provided for guidance...

```
Dim RS As DAO.Recordset
Dim SQL As String

'ordering is only important if you want the FIRST three MIDs.
'If you don't care, just omit the "order by MID" part.
SQL = "select top 3 MID from DealContent where DealID = xxx order by MID"

Set RS = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(SQL)
Do While Not RS.EOF
    Me!MID = Me!MID & RS("mid") & " "
    RS.MoveNext
Loop
RS.Close
Set RS = Nothing
```

I get what most of the code is doing but can't figure out how to make/alter my code to do:

```
Set RS = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(SQL)
Do While Not RS.EOF
    Me!MID = Me!MID & RS("mid") & " "
    RS.MoveNext
```

Comment: Nevermind the message about Max age.

Comment: Are you TRYING to put multiple values into a Dim? Or are you only wanting to store one value?

Comment: I don't quite understand your question.  There are multiple rows that could have MinAge values.  I am trying to make certain that none of them are null.   so, I guess there would be multiple values into the dim

Comment: Rather than try and pull the value from the table to see if the user entered it, you could add code to the forms `BEFORE_UPDATE` event and check the controls on the form using `If IsNull(Me.txtAge) THEN....` or `If IsNull([txtAge]) THEN....`

Comment: I have that code...  However, it the user never touches (updates the box), then a null value can still exist.  When the user uses the toggle button to move to the next section, I would like the code to validate the data again

Answer (score 0):

The answer that Gustav provided will only work for one row. Dlookup cannot handle more than one record. You will need to use a recordset. Please see the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11197521/4731063)

Comment: I see how that works...  but trying to figure out how it fits into my work   Dim RS As DAO.Recordset
Dim SQL As String

'ordering is only important if you want the FIRST three MIDs.
'If you don't care, just omit the "order by MID" part.
SQL = "select top 3 MID from DealContent where DealID = xxx order by MID"

Set RS = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(SQL)
Do While Not RS.EOF
    Me!MID = Me!MID & RS("mid") & " "
    RS.MoveNext
Loop
RS.Close
Set RS = Nothing

Comment: I get the part of creating a SQL...  But the portion where do while not to loop...

Comment: I don't understand what to use there

Comment: Edit your question to better explain what you are trying achieve.

Comment: Ok...  I have a table, which is populated by a user from a form.  The user will enter a series of age ranges (min and max)...  0 - 5, 6 - 10, etc...  each min / max range will be on its own row...  I need to write code that will check each row for two things...  1) that there aren't any fields (min or max) that are null...  2) that the min range is not greater or equal to the max range...

Comment: With the code provided in the link....  I using the record set and understand writing an SQL to query the data...  what I do not understand is how I can get my requirements into the Do While Not to Loop portion of the code

Comment: Updated the question

Comment: Updated the question here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45422737/ms-access-validate-data-in-tables-using-vba)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Dim MinAgeVal As Variant
MinAgeVal = DLookup("[MinAge]", "User_ProductDefaultsAge")

If IsNull(MinAgeVal) Then
    x = MsgBox("Missing Minimum Age Value", vbCritical)
Else
    x = MsgBox("clear", vbCritical)
End If
```

Comment: This worked for one row of data.  The can be multiple rows...  In that case, if failed on multiple rows

Comment: Would I loop it, or would that always pick up the first value?

Comment: It's a mess. First you look up MinAge, then a MID from a different table.

Comment: updated question [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45422737/ms-access-validate-data-in-tables-using-vba)